# Selenium webdriver in c# to select a value in autocomplete

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is an input text box as follows

```
<input class="text-box single-line ui-autocomplete-input valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Initiator field is required." id="InitiatorName" name="InitiatorName" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

On entering a text, an event is fired in jquery which give result. there is no UI element section added to html to display the auto complete values `<li>` tag.
There is a `<span>` tag which is showing value on hover like this :

```
<span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">[object Object]</span>
```

I am not able to retrieve values that came in auto complete so that I can compare them to select a value based on my condition.
This is the Jquery returning data :

```
$("#InitiatorName").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 2,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "my url:,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
        }).done(function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item, index) {
                if (index < 10) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Customer.Id + ' | ' + $.trim(item.Customer.Name) ,
                        value: item.Customer
                    };
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }));
        });
    }
```

I am using selenium webdriver in C# to enter text for autocomplete like this:

```
 var iname = driver.FindElement(By.Id("InitiatorName"));
            iname.SendKeys(initiator);
```

But, I am not getting how to read the autocomplete values so that I can select one based on a condition.

attaching the images of html code:
text box after entering value and its html:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm a little unclear on some of the details, so all of the autocomplete options are contained in that `span` on hover? Are there no UI elements at all for the autocomplete options?

Comment: @mrfreester Hi , yes, I dont have any UI elements, see the screen shots attached. Thanks

Comment: As you push up and down, does that element text change? If so you could keep sending the down arrow to that element and get the text out. Although I'd keep an eye out to see if those elements appear somewhere else in the `html`

Comment: @mrfreester : hi , when I do key down or up only the item is getting highlighted but value is not changing in text box like showed in image. And I have searched so much in my page source and no where values are appearing in html

Comment: It sounds like you'll have to do some unfortunately clever things to get these values then(like select the values one by one to figure out what they are), or request the developers change that control to be more automation friendly. If it's possible to test the values with some sort of unit test, your UI test could just check to see if that list is visible and call it good. Anything you can do to avoid your UI test from being to clever would be good.